# django filter from grouped list

Tags: python, django, list

I have a grouped lists where I am trying to write a query filter.

Grouped list: (listname: group)

```
[({'swtype': 1}, ['201', '203', '205']), ({'swtype': 2}, ['207', '208'])]
```

I am trying to access 201,203,205 from the first group one by one.How can I do that ?

```
f_list = FP.objects.filter(pk__in= group[0])
```

I am trying the above code without success.Should I loop over ?

Comment: But you already have the data, right? Or am I missing something? If I understand it correctly, you have a list of 2-tuples where the second item of a tuple contains the ids.

Comment: `f_list = FP.objects.filter(pk__in= group[0][-1])` ?

Comment: Exactly Willem tuple contains data and the second one is the ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of tuple. The ids are second value in them use `group[0][1]` or `group[0][-1]`

**Ex:**

```
f_list = FP.objects.filter(pk__in= group[0][1])
```

Comment: I was missing the second part [1] ok now it works as I am after :)

Comment: by the way [0][-1] and [0][1] works.What the difference of minus.I didn't see any ?